# Does the topology induced by a finite orthonormal basis have some special properties?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^N \subset H$. We define a map $d:H \times H \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
d(x, y) := \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \langle x-y, e_n \rangle^2} \quad \forall x,y \in H.
$$

First, $d$ is a [pseudo-metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space#Definition) on $H$. Second, the topology $\tau$ induced by $|\cdot|$ is **finer** than the topology $\tau'$ induced by $d$, i.e., $\tau' \subset \tau$.

> We assume that $(e_n)_{n=1}^N$ is an orthonormal set. Does $\tau'$ have some special properties?

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $K$ the subspace spanned by your orthonormal set. Your pseudo-metric is in fact the length of the orthogonal projection of $x-y$ onto $K.$ Is it helpful?

Anyway, to know something special or useful, you should have criteria.